# Error While Adding Visual Web part To Master page in 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2013

I am Trying to add a Visual Web part with Custom css and Java script in it. When i try to add in a layout page It works fine. But when I used the below steps
http://ukreddysharepoint2010.blogspot.in/2014/05/how-to-add-web-part-to-master-page-in.html
 it gives me the below error.
(Screen shot)[image]

Here is the my Ascx and Code of my Visual Web part. Can any one help me On this

ASCX:

```
<link href="../_layouts/15/OwnersWebPart/mbExtruder.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
        body{
           /* font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;*/
          margin:10px;
        }


    </style>
<link href="../_layouts/15/GetSiteOwnersWebPart/mbExtruder.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/GetSiteOwnersWebPart/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../_layouts/15/GetSiteOwnersWebPart/jquery.mb.flipText.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/GetSiteOwnersWebPart/mbExtruder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {


        $("#extruderBottom").buildMbExtruder({
            position: "bottom",
            width: 250,
            extruderOpacity: 1,
            onExtOpen: function () { },
            onExtContentLoad: function () { },
            onExtClose: function () { }
        });

        $.fn.changeLabel = function (text) {
            $(this).find(".flapLabel").html(text);
            $(this).find(".flapLabel").mbFlipText();
        };

    });


</script>


 <div id="extruderBottom" class="{title:'Site Owners'}">
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="MaingrdView" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>  
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>             
               <ul type="circle">                   
                   <li><%#Eval("Name")%></li>
               </ul>              
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>           
    </Columns>     
    </asp:GridView> 
        </div>
```

CS: Code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string CurrentUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

                List<string> MyOwnersList = GetSiteOwner(CurrentUrl);
                DataTable _GetOwners = new DataTable();
                _GetOwners.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[1] { new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)) });
                foreach (var item in MyOwnersList)
                {
                    _GetOwners.Rows.Add(item);
                }
                this.MaingrdView.DataSource = _GetOwners;
                this.MaingrdView.DataBind();
            }



        }

        public List<string> GetSiteOwner(string SiteURL)
        {
            List<String> Owners = new List<String>();
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteURL))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            SPUserCollection siteOwners = web.AssociatedOwnerGroup.Users;
                            foreach (SPUser _User in siteOwners)
                            {
                                Owners.Add(_User.Name);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            });

            return Owners;
        }
```

Here is my Snippet Toll generated Code:

```
<!--CS: Start GetSiteOwnersWebPart - GetSiteOwners Snippet--><!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="aeb98fba8"  Namespace="GetSiteOwnersWebPart.GetSiteOwners" Assembly="GetSiteOwnersWebPart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c03c5188f3869975" %>--><!--MS:<aeb98fba8:GetSiteOwners runat="server" Description="My Visual Web Part" ImportErrorMessage="&#60;%$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;%&#62;" Title="GetSiteOwnersWebPart - GetSiteOwners" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{5d4e0faa-2e53-4745-8640-0f052985eb12}" WebPart="true" IsClosed="false" ID="g_5d4e0faa_2e53_4745_8640_0f052985eb12">--><!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><div id="ctl00_g_5d4e0faa_2e53_4745_8640_0f052985eb12" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{5d4e0faa-2e53-4745-8640-0f052985eb12}" WebPart="true"></div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW--><!--ME:</aeb98fba8:GetSiteOwners>--><!--CE: End GetSiteOwnersWebPart - GetSiteOwners Snippet-->
```

**Error:**

```
System.Web.HttpException: Type 'GetSiteOwnersWebPart.GetSiteOwners.GetSiteOwners' does not have a public property named 'div'.    at System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.GetChildPropertyBuilder(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Type& childType, TemplateParser templateParser, Boolean defaultProperty)     at System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.CreateChildBuilder(String filter, String tagName, IDictionary attribs, TemplateParser parser, ControlBuilder parentBuilder, String id, Int32 line, VirtualPath virtualPath, Type& childType, Boolean defaultProperty)at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessBeginTag(Match match, String inputText)at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)bb88009d-9f7b-0027-380f-59fafab75b46
```

Comment: Amal the funniest thing is i can not find any error with the co-relation id in my log files.

Comment: It works fine when i add it to a sharepoint page. problem is with the master page

Comment: I added the Error Section in my original question. Can you please help me Amal

Comment: Not sure. Just try removing the div from user control.

Comment: I tried the same and still it is not working. I commented my code and just added a ascx page. but still it gives me the same error. Is this Because i am using runWithElevated Privilages in m code.???